# Не отправляет сообщения

Tags: php, mysql

Из `post.php` не добавляет автора в БД, в `index.php`, соответственно, не получает сообщение

index.php

```
 <?php
include '../core/init.php';
$id = (int)$_GET['user_id'];
if($id == 0)
 exit('Ид пользователя не передан');
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id`='".$id."'"));
if(!isset($row['user_id']))
 exit('Пользователя в базе нет');
echo '<img width = 120 height=150 src="../' . $row['profile'] . '"/>';
if (isset($_GET['user_id'])) {$id =$_GET['user_id']; } 
else
{ exit("Вы зашил на страницу без параметра!");} 
if (!preg_match("|^[\d]+$|", $id)) {
exit("<p>Неверный формат запроса! Проверьте URL</p>");
}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id`='$id'"); 
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if (empty($myrow['username'])) { exit("Пользователя не существует! Возможно он был удален.");}

?>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $myrow['username']; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Пользователь "<?php echo $myrow['username']; ?>"</h2>

<?php
print <<<HERE
<br>|<a href='../index.php'>Моя страница</a></br>
HERE;
if ($myrow['username'] == $login) {
print <<<HERE
<h2>Личные сообщения:</h2>
HERE;
$tmp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `poluchatel`='$login' ORDER BY `user_id` DESC"); 
$messages = mysql_fetch_array($tmp);
if (!empty($messages['user_id'])) {
do 
  {
$author = $messages['author'];

  printf("
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td>Автор: <a href='user/index.php?user_id=%s'>%s</a><br>
      Дата: %s<br>
      Сообщение:<br>
     %s<br>

  </td>  
  </tr>
  </table><br>
  ",$author,$messages['date'],$messages['text'],$messages['user_id']);
  }
  while($messages = mysql_fetch_array($tmp));
                    }
                    else {
                    echo "Сообщений нет";
                    }
}
else
{

print <<<HERE
<form action='post.php' method='post'>
<br>
<h2>Отправить Ваше сообщение:</h2>
<textarea cols='43' rows='4' name='text'></textarea><br>
<input type='hidden' name='poluchatel' value='$myrow[username]'>
<input type='hidden' name='user_id' value='$myrow[user_id]'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Отправить'>
</form>
HERE;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

post.php

```
   <?php
include '../core/init.php';
protect_page();

$login = $_POST['username'];

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$login'"); 
$myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);

if (isset($_POST['user_id'])) { $id = $_POST['user_id'];}
if (isset($_POST['text'])) { $text = $_POST['text'];}
if (isset($_POST['poluchatel'])) { $poluchatel = $_POST['poluchatel'];}

$author = $_POST['author'];
$date = date("Y-m-d");

$text = stripslashes($text);
$text = htmlspecialchars($text);

$result2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `messages` (`author`, `poluchatel`, `date`, `text`) VALUES ('$author','$poluchatel','$date','$text')");
echo "<html><head><meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='1; URL=index.php?user_id=".$id."'></head></html>";
?>
```

Comment: Мой вам совет, чтоб быстрее получить ответ, [приведите код нормальный вид](http://irbis-team.com/15/1/11). Думаю, что не только мне, но и другим, облом разгребать эту кашу.

Comment: он нормального вида, может просто для кого то он слишком большой?

Comment: Выбрось курсы попова

Answer (score 1):

Допишите еще одни инпут  после

```
<textarea cols='43' rows='4' name='text'></textarea>
```

добавить

```
<input type='text' name='author' value='Я аффтор'>
```

И да, выбросите эти курсы

Answer (score 0):

> Можете злиться на критику или можете
> отнестись к ней, как хорошему совету,
> но до тех пор, пока вы будете
> следовать курсам Попова, плевки в
> сторону вашего кода не прекратятся
> никогда.

Проверить ваш код в действии я не могу, так же не смогу привести его в идеальный вид, но попробуйте изменить его так:

**index.php**

```
<?php
include '../core/init.php';
$id = (int)$_GET['user_id'];
if($id == 0){
    exit('Ид пользователя не передан');
} else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id`='".$id."'";
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
        echo '<img width = 120 height=150 src="../' . $row['profile'] . '"/>';
    } else {
        exit('Пользователя не существует! Возможно он был удален.');
    }
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $row['username']; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Пользователь "<?php echo $row['username']; ?>"</h2>

<?php
echo "<br>|<a href='../index.php'>Моя страница</a></br>";
if ($row['username'] == $login) {
    echo "<h2>Личные сообщения:</h2>";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `poluchatel`='$login' ORDER BY `user_id` DESC";
    $tmp = mysql_query($query);
    if (mysql_num_rows($tmp) > 0) {
        while($messages = mysql_fetch_assoc($tmp)) {
            $author = $messages['author'];
            printf("<table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            Автор: <a href='user/index.php?user_id=%s'>%s</a><br>
                            Дата: %s<br>
                            Сообщение:<br>
                            %s<br>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table><br>",$author,$messages['date'],$messages['text'],$messages['user_id']);
        }
    } else {
        echo "Сообщений нет";
    }
} else {
    echo "<form action='post.php' method='post'><br>
          <h2>Отправить Ваше сообщение:</h2>
          <textarea cols='43' rows='4' name='text'></textarea><br>
          <input type='hidden' name='poluchatel' value='$row[username]'>
          <input type='hidden' name='user_id' value='$row[user_id]'>
          <input type='hidden' name='author' value='ПУШКИН'>
          <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Отправить'>
          </form>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**post.php**

```
<?php
include '../core/init.php';
protect_page();

$login = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
// не знаю, зачем этот запрос, но вам виднее
$query = "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$login'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query); 
$myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);

if (!empty($_POST['user_id'])) $id = (int)$_POST['user_id'];
if (!empty($_POST['author'])) $author = $_POST['author'];
if (!empty($_POST['poluchatel'])) $poluchatel = $_POST['poluchatel']; 
if (!empty($_POST['text'])) $text = $_POST['text'];
$date = date("Y-m-d");
if (isset($id, $author, $poluchatel,$text)) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `messages` 
             (`author`, `poluchatel`, `date`, `text`) 
             VALUES 
             ('".mysql_real_escape_string($author)."',
             '".mysql_real_escape_string($poluchatel)."',
             '".mysql_real_escape_string($text)."',
             '$date')";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query);
    if($result2) {
        echo "<html><head><meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='1; URL=index.php?user_id=".$id."'></head></html>";
    } else {
        echo '<p>Ошибка! '.mysql_error().'</p>Запрос: '.$query;
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Если выбьет ошибка, то поведайте нам о ней.

Comment: чудеса какие то в author в БД добавляется ???????, в текст дата, дата остается как определено, и сообщений по прежднему нет

Comment: с датой и текстом косяк исправил, но остально по прежднему так же

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, Мде... Определить где у вас может быть ошибка, не видя всей картины в целом, очень сложно.

Ох... Упаковывайте ваш сайт вместе с дампом БД и выкладывайте где-нибудь. Иначе это просто тыканье пальцем в небо... Помогу, только если пообещаете, что курсы Попова "фтопку", а хорошую книгу по программированию - в руки.

Comment: с чем определятся? четко и ясно написал, что одну проблему исправил, а Попов, Пупкин, Васечкин мне до лампочки главное что бы работало, все работает на другом сайте, я всего лишь передрал